# How to convert escape codes in a wxString

Tags: c++, escaping, converters, wxstring

I'm using a `wxWebView` to retrieve the displayed contents of a webpage (using `GetPageText( )`). This returns me a `wxString`.

This `wxString` contains a lot of text, including names, such as D\u00e1vid K\u00e1m\u00e1n (instead of Dávid Káán)

I then process the string, split it into its various components, and display some of the values (& names) in a `wxGrid`.

What I am looking for is a way to convert the `wxString` containing the escape coded characters into a `wxString` that will contain the actual characters so that I can display the correct output in the `wxGrid`.

I can't see any obvious method available though...

Comment: The obvious method is to search the string for "\u" then convert the next four hexadecimal characters to the required character and then replace the escape sequence with the character just created. Are you saying you need help doing that? Any particular part you are stuck on? Normally we like to see that you've made some effort yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious method could be to use regular expressions to find these places, and replace them with the actual letter. Do it in a loop until no matches are found.